# Convert JSON dataframe to lines of plain-text json with R

Tags: json, r, dataframe, jsonlite

I need to transform a json table to lines of json:

To go from:

```
[{"field1": "ABC","field2": "DEF"},
{"field1": "GHI","field2": "JKL"}]
```

To an plain-text file where each line is valid json, like:

```
{"field1": "ABC","field2": "DEF"}
{"field1": "GHI","field2": "JKL"}
```

I realize I could do this through a regular expression, but would rather use an existing method if one exists.

Found http://jsonlines.org/ , which is what I'm trying to do, but didn't see a package for it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Try the `jsonlite` library:

```
library(jsonlite)
text <- '[{"field1": "ABC","field2": "DEF"}, {"field1": "GHI","field2": "JKL"}]'
x <- fromJSON(text) # convert to data.frame
stream_out(x, file("file.json")) # save as newline-delimited JSON
```